# How to create a folder in Outlook from a windows form application using VB

Tags: vb.net

This is my last hope!!
i am trying to manipulate (create, move and delete) folder in an windows form app. i am coding in VB and my outlook is Outlook16 and coding with visual studio 2019.

Thank you, all inputs and tricks will help.

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project you have to add a reference (Project -> Add reference -> COM section) to "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library".

Here is VERY BASIC sample code to manipulate folders:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Const FOLDER_NAME = "My New Folder"

        ' Open Outlook
        Dim App = New Outlook.Application

        'Get Inbox and Drafts folders
        Dim Inbox = App.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
        Dim Drafts = App.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts)

        ' Create a new folder inside Inbox
        Inbox.Folders.Add(FOLDER_NAME)

        ' Create a subfolder
        Inbox.Folders.Item(FOLDER_NAME).Folders.Add("My Subfolder")

        ' Move it from Inbox to Drafts
        Inbox.Folders.Item(FOLDER_NAME).MoveTo(Drafts)

        ' Delete it
        Drafts.Folders.Item(FOLDER_NAME).Delete()

        ' Close Outlook
        App.Quit()

        ' Cleanup
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Inbox)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Drafts)
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(App)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you Disti, it did help but now i am trying to create a folder in a flode in the Inbox.....Inbox;;;;JOBS...(this is where i would like to create a folder  i have tried